# Compiling C program in C++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, g++

I wrote a program in C and I want to use C++ library in this code, I though that I will be able to compile the C in g++ since C++ built in top of C. However, I couldn't do that and the main error was because in one part of the code I wrote a function to read data from input file, before the main function. That worked well in C compiler but not in Cpp compiler.
Below is some of the error messages I got, so I'd like to get general comments and points to take into consideration when use c and cpp interchangeably

```
 error : ‘get_inputs’ was not declared in this scope 

error: use of parameter outside function body before ‘]’ token
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What should I do to fix these errors, shouldnt C++ compiler be able to compile C ???

Comment: We can't fix errors in code we can't see.

Comment: C++ is NOT completely upper compatible with C.

Comment: "since C++ built in top of C". Although C++ started that way, the two languages have deviated since. C has implicit forward declarations for one thing, which could be the problem here.

Comment: gpp can use to compile c file. pls show me your code.

Comment: "C++ built in top of C." And Italian built on top of Latin, but you can't really expect to fully understand a Latin text if you only speak Italian. C and C++ are distinct languages and while they have a large *common* subset (almost all of C overlaps a large part of C++), one is not a subset of the other.

Comment: I see the code in the message. Stop Using dynamic array based on another arugment in the argument and use pointer or something.

Comment: If you compile your program with a C compiler and all warnings enabled, you will get a warning like "implicit declaration of...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following program compiles in C with a warning such as: *'bar' undefined; assuming extern returning int*

```
void foo()
{
  bar(5);
}

int bar(int x)
{
   return x*2;
}
```

If you want this to compile in C++ you must declare `bar` before you use it:

```
int bar(int x);   // forward declaration

void foo()
{
  bar(5);
}

int bar(int x)
{
  return x*2;
}
```

Even in C it's good practice to use forward declarations and to enable all compiler warnings otherwise the error in following program will slip through:

```
void foo()
{
  bar();  // calling bar without argument....
}

int bar(int x)
{
  return x*2;   // ... will result in an undefined value for x here
}
```

Comment: It compiles perfectly, As you said I didnt declare the variables before using them in the function. I really appreciate your answer